# calculating huge numbers in C#

Tags: c#, biginteger

i have a problem the product of multiplying three numbers in my program, Even after BigInteger type.

I don't get any meaningful number.

Please check the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    denss:
    string  density;
    int den;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the density value in kg/m3");
    density = Console.ReadLine();
    bool dens = int.TryParse(density, out den);
    if (dens == false)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only");
        goto denss;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(den);

    velss:

    string velocity;
    int vel;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the velocity value in m/s");
    velocity = Console.ReadLine();
    bool vels = int.TryParse(velocity, out vel);
    if (vels == false)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only");
        goto velss;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(vel);

    lengt:

    string length;
    int len;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the length value in m");
    length = Console.ReadLine();
    bool leng = int.TryParse(length, out len);
    if (leng == false)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only");
        goto lengt;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(len);

    BigInteger rel = den * vel * len;

    Console.WriteLine(rel);

    if (rel>100000)
        Console.WriteLine("turbuelent flow. Reynolds no is ", rel);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("laminar flow. Reynolds no is  ", rel);

    Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

The output i get is shown in this photo:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dbEw.png)

Comment: `goto denss;` I would suggest not using goto's in your code.. learn how to write `private static methods` and pass all necessary variables and return values..

Comment: haven't seen GOTOs used like this since BASIC days (barring the occasional kludgy bit of T-SQL). There are far better ways to structure the code. As for "I don't get any meaningful number."...what _do_ you get instead? An error? Some other result?

Comment: @MethodMan  I know that goto is bad after several posts about. However, I find it the easiest for the time being. I stopped coding since almost 10 years. In college I used to code using fortan and matlab. I am new to C# and I am trying to be self-taught programmer.

Comment: well self taught or not.. you should google C# .net best practices and programming tutorials, goto's are horrible habit to get back into ...

Answer (score 4):

Amongst other issues, your main problem is the following line:

```
BigInteger rel = den * vel * len;
```

What is happening here is `den * vel * len` is calculated as an `int` because all values involved are `int`. This int overflows and is meaningless. This meaningless number is then assigned to the `BigInteger rel`. What you need is:

```
BigInteger rel = new BigInteger(den) * new BigInteger(vel) * new BigInteger(len);
```

or declare them as `double`, which is what they should have been for this problem domain in the first place.

Comment: All the values (`den`, `vel`, `len`) must be `double` (or `float`) - we really can have `den = 827.96`; `vel = 0.4`; `len = 0.015` - say, beer spills out of the bottle. Is it a laminar or turbulent flow? :)

Answer (score 2):

The code should be

```
if (rel>100000)
        Console.WriteLine("turbuelent flow. Reynolds no is {0}", rel);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("laminar flow. Reynolds no is {0}", rel);
```

And please, don't use gotos

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually outputting the value on the console. The string that you use as the output (the first parameter to WriteLine) must contain a *token* showing where to insert the second parameter (the number) into the string. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("turbuelent flow. Reynolds no is {0}", rel);
```

The `{0}` shows where the parameter should go. If you have multiple parameters to output, you can use `{0}`, `{1}`, and so on.

Actually, your code could be written a bit less repetitively like this:

```
string flowType = "";
if (rel > 100000) flowType = "turbulent";
else flowType = "laminar";
Console.WriteLine("{0} flow. Reynolds no is {1}", flowType, rel);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Too many problems:

- incorrect output `Console.WriteLine("turbuelent flow. Reynolds no is ", rel);` - `{0}` omitted
- `BigInteger rel = den * vel * len;` prone to integer overflow
- wrong types - why `den`, `vel`, `len` are *integers*? Why, say, `len` can't be 15 **cm** = `0.15` meters?
- goto...
- copy/paste

Let's do it right. First of all, decompose your solution, *extract a method*, *do not copy/paste*:

```
//DONE: double, not int - velocity, density and length are not necessary integers
private static double ReadValue(string title) {
  double result = 0.0;

  Console.WriteLine(title);

  while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only");

  return result;  
}
```

Then implement a simple `Main()` without `goto` and other ugly things

```
static void Main() {
  //DONE: double, not int: 
  // what if alcohol travels along a pipe:
  //   density            = 856.96  kg/m3 (some reference value)
  //   velocity           =   3.6   m/s   (5 km/h)
  //   length (diameter?) =   0.015 m     (1.5 cm)
  double den = ReadValue("Please enter the density value in kg/m3"); 
  double vel = ReadValue("Please enter the velocity value in m/s");
  double len = ReadValue("Please enter the length value in m");

  double rel = den * vel * len;

  //DONE: use formatting not a complex logic  
  // F0 - we don't want anything after the decimal point, as if rel is integer 
  Console.WriteLine("{0} flow. Reynolds no is {1:F0}", // string 
    rel > 100000 ? "turbuelent" : "laminar",           // 1st arg
    rel);                                              // 2nd arg

  Console.ReadKey();  
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Dmitry. By the way my beard looks like yours